# How to improve the code standards while using if conditions?

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, switch-statement

Let's say I want to check the particular condition while iterating the list, I am using many if conditions which will violating the coding standards. I have the following code with many if conditions, How can I reduce the number coding lines and improve the quality of the code with out change of my output.

Please suggest me some good standards while using if conditions.

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < 7; colIndex++) {
                if (colIndex == 0) {
                      Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(colIndex);
                      if (cell != null) {
                          firstName = cell.getStringCellValue();
                          System.out.println("First Name : "+firstName);
                      }
                  }
                if (colIndex == 1) {
                    Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(colIndex);
                    if (cell != null) {
                        middleName = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        System.out.println("Middle Name : "+middleName);
                    }
                }
                if (colIndex == 2) {
                    Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(colIndex);
                    if (cell != null) {
                        lastName = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        System.out.println("Last Name : "+lastName);
                    }
                }
                if (colIndex == 3) {
                    Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(colIndex);
                    if (cell != null) {
                        email = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        System.out.println("Email : "+email);
                    }
                }
                if (colIndex == 4) {
                    Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(colIndex);
                    if (cell != null) {
                        password = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        System.out.println("Password : "+password);
                    }
                }
                if (colIndex == 5) {
                    Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(colIndex);
                    if (cell != null) {
                        role = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        System.out.println("Role : "+role);
                    }
                }
                if (colIndex == 6) {
                    Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(colIndex);
                    if (cell != null) {
                        status = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        System.out.println("Status : "+status);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: Use switch instead  if == 1 if == 2, check this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: IMO, this question is more suited for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a perfect opportunity for an `enum`:

```
enum Field {

    FirstName,
    MiddleName,
    LastName,
    EMail,
    Password,
    Role,
    Status;
}

public void test() {
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Row nextRow = iterator.next();
        Map<Field, String> values = new EnumMap(Field.class);
        for (Field f : Field.values()) {
            Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(f.ordinal());
            if (cell != null) {
                values.put(f, cell.getStringCellValue());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Given the fact he maybe is not able to refactor outside code (that would access the map) he then still have to assign all those values at the end. `firstName = values.get(Field.FirstName);` and so on.

Comment: @lschuetze - Likely the fields will be put in a bean rather than a `Map`. I have used a `Map` for simplicity here.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon, You suggested the great solution. But how can I handle If I need to get the date value from the cell instead String/Text? I have 20 columns in my excel, but the 7th and 8th cell values are date columns, So I am getting error while getting the date values. So please suggest me how can I fetch the date values of the cell.

Answer (score 2):

First of all shift `if` to `switch`. And then you can reduce the top two lines in each condition with writing only once

```
 for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < 7; colIndex++) {
 Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(colIndex);
 if (cell != null) {
  value= cell.getStringCellValue();
  switch (intParam) {
     case 1:
     System.out.println("First Name : "+firstName);
     break;
     case 2 : 
     // and so on.. 
  }
 }
```

Note : don't have IDE in hand, resolve if any compile time errors.

Answer (score 2):

Depends how fixed your columns are. Since you are not gaining much out of it at the moment using the for loop you could even directly store the data.

```
...
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  Row next = iterator.next();
  firstName = saveGetCell(firstName, 0, next);
  middleName = saveGetCell(middleName, 1, next);
  lastName = saveGetCell(lastName, 2, next);
  email = saveGetCell(email, 3, next);
  password = saveGetCell(password, 4, next);
  role = saveGetCell(role, 5, next);
  status = saveGetCell(status, 6, next);
}

private String saveGetCell(String saveValue, int index, Row row) {
  Cell cell = row.getCell(index);
  String result = null;
  if(cell != null) {
    result = cell.getStringCellValue();
  }
  return result == null ? saveValue : result;
}
```

Comment: previously I have only 7 columns so I called the method for 7 times. Now I have 70 columns, If I call the method for 70 times will that make sense?  How can I handle If I have 70 columns.

Comment: Since I don't know the framework you are using I'd say you should use (or implement yourself) something like Eclipse SWT [TableViewer's](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FTableViewer.html) ItemProvider and LabelProvider and just put your objects in and they get properly displayed. This will also seperate the different concerns involved here. Having 70 different columns could also exhibit some poor user experience.

Answer (score 1):

Use `switch statement` for the `if` as follows. 
When you use switch in the worst case the compiler will generate the same code as a `if-else` chain. Other times it will give better performance than `if-else` anything. Its better to use most common cases 1st into the switch statement.

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Row nextRow = iterator.next();
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < 7; colIndex++) {

    switch(colIndex){
        case 0 :
              Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(colIndex);
              if (cell != null) {
                  firstName = cell.getStringCellValue();
                  System.out.println("First Name : "+firstName);
              }
        break;  
        case 1 :
            Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(colIndex);
            if (cell != null) {
                middleName = cell.getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println("Middle Name : "+middleName);
            }
            break;
        case 2 :
            Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(colIndex);
            if (cell != null) {
                lastName = cell.getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println("Last Name : "+lastName);
            }
            break;
        case 3 :
            Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(colIndex);
            if (cell != null) {
                email = cell.getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println("Email : "+email);
            }
            break;
        case 4 :
            Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(colIndex);
            if (cell != null) {
                password = cell.getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println("Password : "+password);
            }
            break;
        case 5 :
            Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(colIndex);
            if (cell != null) {
                role = cell.getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println("Role : "+role);
            }
            break;
        case 6 :
            Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(colIndex);
            if (cell != null) {
                status = cell.getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println("Status : "+status);
            }
        break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void CycleFunc()
{
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < 7; colIndex++) 
            {
                String result = GetCellStatus(colIndex);
                System.out.println(result); 
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
}

private string GetCellStatus(int colIndex)
{
    String result;
    switch(colIndex)
    {
    case:0: 
        result = "Middle Name : "+GetStingFromCell(colIndex);
        break;
    case:1: 
        result = "Last Name : "+GetStingFromCell(colIndex);
        break;
    case:2: 
        result = "Email : "+GetStingFromCell(colIndex);
        break;
    case:3: 
        result = "Password: "+GetStingFromCell(colIndex);
        break;
    case: 4: 
        result = "Role : "+GetStingFromCell(colIndex);
        break;
    case:5: 
        result = "Status : "+GetStingFromCell(colIndex);
        break;
    case:6: 
        result = "Middle Name : "+GetStingFromCell(colIndex);
        break;
    default: 
        result = "Some error";
        break;
    }
    return result;
}

private string GetStingFromCell(int colIndex)
{
    String str;
    Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(colIndex);
                      if (cell != null) {
                          str = cell.getStringCellValue();
                      }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the code stays the same in each branch:

```
Cell cell = nextRow.getCell(colIndex);
String value = null;
if (cell != null) {
    value = cell.getStringCellValue(); // the name of the variable differs here, but it's always a string?
```

...so you can do that before your if-block. If it's not always a String, you can at least the get cell before the if. Then you could use a switch-case...

```
switch(colIndex) {
    case 1: firstName = value; break;
//etc.
```

If the branches are complicated, you might think about using an enum for that.

```
enum CellValue {

    FIRST_NAME(0) {
        public void doSomething(Cell cell) {
            ...do something.
        }
     },

     // etc.

     private final int colIndex;

     private CellValue(int colIndex) {
         this.colIndex = colIndex;
     }

    public abstract void doSomething(Cell cell);

    public static void work(int colIndex, Something nextRow) {
        for(CellValue value : values()) {
            if (value.colIndex == colIndex) {
                value.work(newRow.getCell(colIndex));
                return;  
            }
        }
        // throw exception here
    }
}
```

This way, you then can simply call...

```
CellValue.work( colIndex, nextRow );
```